# Create an arrow in css3

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I know how to create arrows outside the div by using the psedo class but I need to create a arrow inside the div as shown below

[image]

How can I get this?

Comment: Pseudo-element, not a pseudo-class. =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to use extra elements, this can be done entirely using CSS3:

```css
background-color: gray;
background-image: 
   linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 75%, #000 75%), /*right side of triangle*/
   linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #000 75%)   /*left side of triangle*/;
background-position: 30px 0, 0 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 30px 30px;
```

Demo (with vendor-prefixes: http://jsfiddle.net/rLZkf/1/).

### Explanation of a this triangle technique

As seen in the image below <sup>[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient#Gradient_at_a_45_degree_angle)</sup>, CSS supports linear colour gradients using a simple syntax.

[image]

With some imagination, you can see a triangle in the previous image. The colour blends at the diagonal though. So, we set explicit colour stop locations. When these locations are equal, there's no visual blending any more, and you get a solid triangle.

It's time to introduce a triangle:

```css
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, black 50%);
```

The gradient starts at the bottom-left corner, and ends at the upper-right corner due to the angle of 45°. The colour stop location is defined to be 50%, so the bottom-left part of the triangle is transparent, and the other half is black. To get a different triangle, use an angle of 135°. Here's an image with both angles:

[image]

At this point, we know how to create a rectangular triangle. To get further, we need to be able to create a triangle where the hypotenuse is placed vertically or horizontally. To achieve this, we join two triangles. CSS3 introduces support for [multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds). This feature is used to construct the triangle.

```css
/* Create triangles */
background-image: 
   linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 75%, #000 75%), /*right side of triangle*/
   linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #000 75%)   /*left side of triangle*/;
/* Move one of the triangles to the right */
background-position: 30px 0, 0 0;
/* Don't repeat the background image (remove this to see what would happen) */
background-repeat: no-repeat;
/* Define the size of the triangle */
background-size: 30px 30px;
```

In the previous CSS code, one can see that I'm using `75%` as a colour stop location (instead of `50%`). This choice does not matter, the final shape of the triangle is determined by the values of the gradient's colour stop location, `background-position` and `background-size`.

**Note: I left out the vendor prefixes in the explanation. To use this technique, you have to add the vendor-prefixes (as seen in [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rLZkf/1/)).

### Relevant documentation

- [Multiple CSS backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds)
- [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient)
- [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-position)
- [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size)
- [`background-repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-repeat)

Comment: Looks like a really fresh solution. Would you please explain in detail how triangle form is achieved?

Comment: @PavloMykhalov Added explanation to the answer.

Comment: @RobW In FF17.0.1, your demo is broken: the triangles do not form an arrowhead.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look there I think :
http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: But my requirement is nt there in tat link :(

Answer (score 1):

..........................

Now used to

```
after:  pseudo-class
```

as like this

```
.some{
width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.some:after{
content:'';
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;
  top:-11px;
z-index:0;
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  background:green;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Opera */
}
```

***[live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/tKiPi5md)***

Comment: Cool but the trhing is my div has no fixed width and height so couldnt use overflow:hidden which u have shown. Otherwise its nice answer

Answer (score 1):

Shortest and most browser-compatible solution:

css:

```
​div{
    position:relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: gray;
}
div::after{
    content: '';
    border: solid 15px transparent;
    border-top-color:black;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 30px;
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/7bP9q/